# Linking multiple firebase projects with a single analytics property

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have multiple firebase projects I want to link to a single google analytics property. Every time I try to create a link to analytics from the firebase project, it creates a new analytics property, instead of linking it with an existing one. Is there a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because currently only support a single firebase link to a GA4F.
The [answer](https://www.kristaseiden.com/new-app-web-properties-in-google-analytics/#comment-70556) from GA team.

> Right now it’s one Firebase project which allows you to create multiple streams of data in GA. by Krista